# How do I get this Laravel redirect to work?

Tags: laravel, forms, redirect, controller, store

I created an app with an html form and a store method to save the info to the database (blog post with a picture). After the store function is executed I want to redirect the user to the index page.
Everything works except for that last part. In the debug bar I can see the index View being rendered, but the create View is still being shown in the browser as if nothing happened at all. Not a single solution I could find online has worked for me. Deleting cache etc. didn't solve anything either.

Relevant routes:

```php
Route::get('/blog', [PostsController::class, 'index'])->name('blog.index');
Route::get('/blog/create', [PostsController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/blog/create', [PostsController::class, 'store'])->name('blog.store');
```

Create function in PostsController:

```php
public function create()
{
    return view('blog.create');
}
```

Create view:

```xml
<form action="" method="POST" class="u-clearfix u-form-spacing-10 u-form-vertical u-inner-form" name="form">
  @csrf
  <div class="u-form-group u-form-name u-block-1619-8">
    <label class="u-label u-block-1619-9">Headline</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Write a powerful headline here" id="name-26cf" name="headline" class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle u-white u-block-1619-10" required>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group u-form-message u-block-1619-14">
    <label class="u-label u-block-1619-15">Article text</label>
    <textarea placeholder="Write the article here" rows="20" cols="50" id="message-26cf" name="fulltext" class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle u-white u-block-1619-16" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group u-form-message u-block-1619-14">
    <label class="u-label u-block-1619-15">Article picture</label><br>
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="photo" required>
  </div>
  <div class="u-align-left u-form-group u-form-submit u-block-1619-17">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="u-btn u-btn-submit u-button-style u-block-1619-18">
  </div>
</form>
```

Store function in PostsController:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,webp,png,gif,bmp,tiff|max:8192']);
    $imgName = date("YmdHms").'photo.'.$request->photo->extension();
    $request->photo->move(public_path('img'), $imgName);

    $newPost = BlogPost::create([
        'headline' => $request->headline,
        'fulltext' => $request->fulltext,
        'photo' => $imgName, 
        'datetime' => date("Y-m-d H:m:s")
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('blog.index');
}
```

Blogpost model:

```php
class BlogPost extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['headline', 'fulltext', 'photo', 'datetime'];
}
```

Laravel Debur Bar showing the index page being rendered:

[image: Laravel Debug Bar showing the index page being rendered]

Comment: Are you certain the contents of `resources\views\blog\index.blade.php` is different than `resources\views\blog\create.blade.php`? Try running `php artisan view:clear` to clear the cached views just in case.